# How can I make two UILabels appear side by side?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, constraints

I have two UILabels :

```
            let wordLabel               = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,(self.view.frame.width - 30) / 2,0))
            wordLabel.text              = word.valueForKey("sanskrit") as? Stringsize: 16)
            wordLabel.numberOfLines     = 0
            wordLabel.sizeToFit()
            wordLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            let englishWordLabel           = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(wordLabel.frame.width + 10,0,labelWidth,0))
            englishWordLabel.text          = word.valueForKey("english") as? Stringsize: 16)
            englishWordLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            englishWordLabel.sizeToFit()
            englishWordLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
            englishWordLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Basically, I have an array of these stacked up inside the cell of a UITableView.

To neaten it up, I wanted to give roughly half the space to each UILabel ( minus some padding ). `wordLabel` on the left. `englishWordLabel` on the right.

What blows my mind right now, is that if I remove the `sizeToFit` line, then the sizing works, but my entire wordLabel is completely missing. I can add a border to it to see it in preview, or debug the View Hierarchy, and it's completely missing. Add `sizeToFit`, and my label appears, but the width is ignored ( that part I understand ).

I thought about adding Constraints to accomplish this job, but I'm not sure if that's the best strategy.

What would you recommend doing to accomplish this?

Comment: You need autolayout. The easiest way for you is a horizontal `UIStackView` set to `Fill Equally`; this will allow you to have two labels taking the same width side-by-side with basically no effort. You can also adjust the padding as well. You can also embed multiple "lines" of the label `UIStackView`'s inside a vertical `UIStackView`.

Comment: Ah cool @RoboticCat . Thanks for the advice. What is "autolayout" exactly?

Comment: One of the reasons to layout views & view controllers in IB is so that you can get the constraints correct at design time rather than going through the whole code->compile->test->code cycle. In IB you can see your views & view controllers for every device in every orientation at design time. IB will also show errors & warnings for constraints that do not work. For some reason, some developers do not understand auto layout (and certainly do not understand its power) so I suggest you review a tutorial first.

Comment: Also, `UIStackView`s implement constraints for you automagically so all you need to do is pin the `UIStackView` to the correct position in your view and then set properties on the `UIStackView`. For more info look at the (free) WWDC 2015 video `Mysteries of Auto Layout Part 1`: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/ . There are also other useful videos in WWDC 2015 and previous years and also example code.

Comment: @RoboticCat Very cool. Great to know. Thanks so much for the infos. This was my first iOS project, so I wanted to learn how to make something exclusively from both code and from storyboard. Thanks so much for the tips!

Comment: I understand - the OS X / iOS frameworks are powerful and enormous. This makes the first few apps quite tricky because it is not clear which technologies to use in which situations. Of course, once you've learnt the frameworks it all becomes much, much simpler. Also, don't underestimate Apple's documentation - it is information dense (making it tricky to read) but contains extremely valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Robotic Cat mentioned, it seems like what you're looking for is **Auto Layout**.

Auto Layout enables you to set constraints on views programmatically and/or in storyboard. These constraints allow you to create adaptive layouts based on screen sizes, view bounds/frames, relative width/height, and many other things. To get you started, I've provided a Ray Wenderlich tutorial about Auto Layout, as well as some helpful Apple Documentation.

- [Apple's Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)
- [Ray Wenderlich Auto Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: I'm doing my setup programmatically. Does auto layout still make sense?

Comment: If everything is programmatic, I'd suggest at least setting constraints on your views in code.

Comment: Right. That's what I have. But what kind of constraints then? Like I described in my question, if I set constraints, everything goes all over the place. There doesn't seem to be any logic to it. I've read those links you mentioned over the past couple months as well. My intuition has me write the width, and leading space, but then my two UILabels just sit on top of each other.

Comment: To separate your labels, you'll want to set the leading constraint of wordLabel equal to the leading edge of your tableView cell, and the trailing constraint of englishWordLabel to the trailing edge of your tableView cell. PS: A screenshot of what is happening, and what you want it to look like would be very helpful.